# getting sporadic ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException

Tags: android, view, thread-safety, android-asynctask

I have an app with a long running action. I am using AsyncTask. In its onPostExecute() I call a function that modifies some views. I am getting this error on calling setEnabled on the 5th view of 10 views being modified. And it happens very seldom, getting the odd error report from users.

Obviously a multithreading issue. But I thought onPostExecute() always runs on the UI thread? Could it be that the UI thread suddenly gets changed to another thread??

Stack Trace:

generated the following exception:
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original
thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

--------- Instruction Stack trace ---------

1. android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:3041)
2. android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:647)
3. android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:673)
4. android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2511)
5. android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5255)
6. android.view.View.invalidateDrawable(View.java:7293)
7. android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:300)
   8.
   android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.selectDrawable(DrawableContainer.java:227)
   9.
   android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.onStateChange(StateListDrawable.java:99)
8. android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState(Drawable.java:400)
9. android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:7374)
10. android.view.ViewGroup.drawableStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:3357)
11. android.widget.FrameLayout.drawableStateChanged(FrameLayout.java:164)
12. android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:7388)
13. android.view.View.setEnabled(View.java:3147)
14. com.voltup.powermax.ac.a(ActivityAppUiProxy.java:383)
15. com.voltup.powermax.cp.onPostExecute(ModeChange.java:1)
16. android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)

Comment: well actually it is not called on UI thread but on thread where AsyncTask was created. Thats why docs say: `The task instance must be created on the UI thread.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I thought onPostExecute() always runs on the UI thread?

Yes, it does. Per Selvin's comment, AFAIK, if you try to create an `AsyncTask` from another thread, it fails.

> Could it be that the UI thread suddenly gets changed to another thread??

No. More likely, you are accidentally going down a code path in `doInBackground()` that is updating the UI.

If you have a full stack trace showing that you are getting this exception from logic executed in `onPostExecute()`, please edit your question and paste in that stack trace.

Comment: adding stack trace. It is getting called from onPostExecute()

Comment: @Yossi: You did not add the stack trace.

Comment: Where are you getting the `View` that you are enabling? Is there some scenario in which that `View` might have been created in a background thread (but attached to the main view hierarchy on the main application thread)?

Comment: The View that I am enabling is a TextSwitcher ; I do have several places in my code where I switch in new text ; I guess I need to hunt down where these may be getting called on the wrong thread?

Comment: @Yossi: It's not so much "called on the wrong thread" as it is "*created* on the wrong thread". That's the only thing I can think of that might explain the behavior, and even that is merely a guess.

Comment: Ok, so this is what I did - I added a catch to the place where this comes from, and in it I cause the TextSwitcher to regenerate new view on current UI thread by calling object.setText(null). Ugly but helpful for this very seldom seen error